# Unknown "Azure Premium Storage" item in bill

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I've just checked my current Azure usage, and I'm seeing an item called...

Premium Storage - Page Blob/P10 (Units) - US West

This item is quite expensive, but I don't know what it is, or how it's been allocated, or how to remove it.

I've checked my storage accounts, vm's, and databases, and confirmed that they're all in Australia.

This is the first time I've noticed this "US West" storage item.

The only new thing I've added to Azure recently is an "S0 Standard (10 DTUs)" database account. However this says it's located in Australia, and it currently has nothing in it. I've checked the resource cost, and it's currently showing $0.

How do I go about figuring out what this mystery storage resource is?

Comment: I would start by downloading the detailed usage data by logging in into account portal (https://accounts.windowsazure.com). May be someone created it and then deleted it.

Comment: Figured it out. It was disk for one of my test VM's. I don't know why the location didn't match the VM. This is what really confused me.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've traced it. It's the disk for one of my VM's. I don't know why the location for the storage is "US West", when the location for the VM is Australia. The VM was created as an experiment and isn't currently being used. I was testing out the new ARM deployment type. My fault for not fully understanding the pricing before creating the resource. I assumed storage cost would be negligible, and that the VM wouldn't cost much if it was deallocated most of the time. Anyway I'll delete the VM, and do more reading about pricing before trying it again.

Comment: Regular storage cost *is* negligible, as you say - a few pennies per GB / month. And, with sparse allocation on vhd's, even a 30GB disks costs pennies if you haven't stored much in it. **However**: *Premium Storage* (SSD) is reserved, pre-allocated storage (as explained in the pricing). So, even when using none of the disk, you are charged the monthly price for the entire allocated disk. In your case, you likely created a Premium Storage OS disk (which is not required when creating DS or GS series VM's). That's why you're seeing the premium storage charge.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon That makes sense. I'll put it down to experience. Just as well I noticed it fairly soon.